# mod-rewrite domainA to domainB with parameters or individually redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have a old domain with a old url structure and want redirect (301) it to an another domain with a new url-structure. I have urls that must be transform individually:

```
http://domainA.com/ => http://ru.domainB.com/
http://domainA.com/?fieldA=abc => http://ru.domainB.com/xxx/zzz
http://domainA.com/?fieldA=www&fieldB=aaa => http://ru.domainB.com/uuu/ooo/ppp
```

another urls have the same values:

```
http://domainA.com/?fieldC=abc&fieldD=4 => http://ru.domainB.com/abc/xxx/4
http://domainA.com/?fieldC=abc&fieldD=5 => http://ru.domainB.com/abc/xxx/5
http://domainA.com/?fieldC=abc&fieldD=6 => http://ru.domainB.com/abc/xxx/6

http://domainA.com/?fieldC=def&fieldD=4 => http://ru.domainB.com/def/xxx/4
http://domainA.com/?fieldC=def&fieldD=5 => http://ru.domainB.com/def/xxx/5
http://domainA.com/?fieldC=def&fieldD=6 => http://ru.domainB.com/def/xxx/6
```

left side urls can have optional "index.php" before "?" or "www." before domain name. Can anybody help me here and translate this 4 links with mod_rewrite(apache), please?

My account have multiple domain-names for one webspace (wildcard subdomains). Pseudo setting in apache conf:

```
ServerAlias *.domainA.com
ServerAlias *.domainB.com
ServerAlias *.domainC.com
ServerAlias *.domainD.com
```

**EDIT: This helps me.**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)domainA\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fieldA=xxx)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)domainA\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fieldA=abc
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/abc/bbb/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.|)domainA\.com
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} fieldA=abc&fieldB=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/abc/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing just a redirect 301 in your .htaccess file?

```
redirect 301 http://domainA.com/ http://ru.domainB.com/
```

**Update:** if you need all 4 of your URLS and they are very specific like you said. Then try this.This should work for all 4 of the URLS.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fieldA=abc(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/xxx/zzz? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fieldA=www&fieldB=aaa(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/uuu/ooo/ppp? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)fieldC=abc&fieldD=4(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/abc/xxx/4? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

**Update 2:**

Try this for the new URL's then. This will match fieldC and fieldD with either `ABC` or `DEF`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fieldC=(.*)&fieldD=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ru.domainB.com/%1/xxx/%2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and hints, but its not 100% what I need. I have edit my text with new Links. I need this only for domainA. In your example every domain for this webspace will use your "RewriteRule".

Comment: Ok, what exactly do you want for doaminA? Do you want it to always have the www or does it matter?

Comment: @user706420 I updated the answer to include the new URL's you added. This should go into your `.htaccess` file in the root of `domainA`. Then these rules will only work for `domainA`.

Comment: I will accept your answer, because it helps me to solve this problem. In your example is code that is not neccessary. In "QUERY_STRING" you wrote: (^|&) and (&|$). You can delete it and its working identical. Integer values in parameters should be (\d+) instead yours (.*), etc... :) Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, but they worked. :) yes I didn't know if it was always going to be a digit. However I could have used \w+. Anyway, glad you got it sorted out.